# Identifying if an element is present or not using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, xpath

I have a SAVE button which is active only if I do some changes and then trying to save it. Otherwise its disabled.

This is the html for that button:

```
<button id="customize-site-save" class="button button--primary" data-ng-class="ButtonController.getCssClasses()" type="button" data-disable-on-call="" data-ng-disabled="PlatformCustomizeSiteController.customizeSiteForm.$pristine" data-ng-click="DisableOnCallController.actionEnabled() && (PlatformCustomizeSiteController.save())" translate-keep-content="true" disabled="disabled">
```

In this HTML, the disabled tag is only active when the button is disabled. How can I check that disabled is active or not?

This is my x path `.//*[@id='customize-site-save']` for the button.

I just want to press the button if there is no disabled tag in the html.

Comment: what you tried so far? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try if following workaround works for you?

```
        IWebElement btnEnabled = driver.FindElement(By.Id("customize-site-save"));
        IWebElement buttonDisabled = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[disabled ='disabled']"));

        bool btnStatus = IsElementPresent(buttonDisabled);
        if (btnStatus== false)
        {
            btnEnabled.Click();
        }


 public bool IsElementPresent(IWebelement element)
    {
        try
        {
          driver.FindElement(element);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working but I took the idea from the above code and done some changes and implemented the checking in another way. 

used the below code to check the save button is enabled or disabled. 

Boolean isPresentbtnEnabled = GlobalVariables.BrowserDriver.findElements(save_button_customize_page).size() > 0; //checking for the enabled save button
  Boolean isPresentbuttonDisabled = GlobalVariables.BrowserDriver.findElements(save_button_Disabled).size() > 0; //checking for the disabled tag (its false when the button is enabled)

after that i used if statement to check true or false

Comment: Cool! I am glad that approach helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PageObject Pattern](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) with [FindBy Annotation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/)

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver,timeOutInSeconds,pollingInterval);

FindBy(id = "customize-site-save")
WebElement saveButton;

public saveWhenReady() {
    return webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(saveButton)).click();
}
```

If you initialise you waits to your QoS requirements, this will only report a fail only if the button does not appear in time.